# How to get the first <ul> element from a document in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

First of all, sorry If it isn't clear in the beginning, but let me explain: I want to get the div with a class and the first `<ul>` from a document (I'm using blogger). I already have a JS that picks up the first image and creates a thumbnail like this:

```
//<![CDATA[
                            function bp_thumbnail_resize(image_url,post_title)
                            {
                              var show_default_thumbnail=true;
                              if(show_default_thumbnail == true && image_url == "") image_url= default_thumbnail;
                              image_tag='<img src="'+image_url.replace('/s72-c/','/')+'" class="postimg" alt="'+post_title+'"/>';
                              if(image_url!="") return image_tag; else return "";
                            }
                            //]]>
```

and below,

```
 document.write(bp_thumbnail_resize(&quot;<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>&quot;,&quot;<data:post.title/>&quot;));
```

Now the structure that I want (because I cannot display the full post in the homepage due to the size of other elements):

```
  <div class="Title1">
    <h3>Title</h3>
  </div>

  <ul>
   <li>DESCRIPTION1</li>
   <li>DESCRIPTION2</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: "I already have a JS that picks up the first image and creates a thumbnail like this:" How is this relevant to your question?

Answer (score 4):

There are number of ways in which you can do that. Few are

```
var firstUL = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
var firstUL = document.querySelector("ul");
```

If you also have Jquery in use

```
$( "ul" ).first();
```

or

```
 $("ul:first")
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to get the first  element from a document in JavaScript?

You could try something as simple as:

```
var firstUlElement = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
```

The `getElementsByTageName` method of `document`

> returns a live HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name. The
>   subtree underneath the specified element is searched, excluding the
>   element itself. The returned list is live, meaning that it updates
>   itself with the DOM tree automatically.

as it is stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName).

Comment: alternatively, `var firstUlElement = document.querySelector('ul');`

Answer (score 1):

```
var firstUl = document.querySelector('ul');
```